# jax-ws response received, but response object empty

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am using wsimport from jdk 6 to create soap webservice client.
To be more specific JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6.

Here is the wsdl

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <wsdl:definitions name="customerSearch" targetNamespace="http://customer-search-gui.ws.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://customer-search-gui.ws.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://customer-search-gui.ws.com">
   <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://customer-search-gui.ws.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:element name="STATUS">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="STATUS_CODE" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="ERROR_CODE" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="ERROR_DESCRIPTION" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="customer">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="firstName" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="lastName" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xsd:element name="zipCode" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:element name="customerSearchCRMRequest">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="searchCriteria">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="firstName" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                                <xsd:element name="lastName" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="trackingId" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="customerSearchCRMResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="customerList">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element ref="tns:customer" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="trackingId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="tns:STATUS"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>         
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="searchCrmRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:customerSearchCRMRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="searchCrmResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="response" element="tns:customerSearchCRMResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="search">
    <wsdl:operation name="searchCrm">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:searchCrmRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:searchCrmResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="searchSOAP" type="tns:search">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="searchCrm">
        <soap:operation soapAction="/searchCrm"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://customer-search-gui.ws.com"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://customer-search-gui.ws.com"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="customerSearch">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:searchSOAP" name="searchSOAP">
        <soap:address location="http://192.192.192.192:10001/customSearch"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Here is request:

```
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:customerSearchCRMRequest xmlns:ns2="http://customer-search-gui.ws.com"><searchCriteria><firstName>John</firstName></searchCriteria><trackingId>track001</trackingId></ns2:customerSearchCRMRequest></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Here is response:

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><customerSearchCRMResponse xmlns="http://customer-search-gui.ws.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><customerList><customer><firstName>John</firstName><lastName>Stone</lastName></customer></customerList><trackingId>track001</trackingId><STATUS><STATUS_CODE>0</STATUS_CODE></STATUS></customerSearchCRMResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So, like you can see there is something in response. But the problem is in java customerSearchCRMResponse object is empty and contains no value!

And there is no error or exception throwns. Everything seems fine. There is obvious problem in deserializing response. But what can I do with that?

Where and what is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried the same thing in the SoapUI?

Comment: `customer-search-gui.ws.com` package and the relevant entities are all available within your setup?

Comment: sorry I don't understand. what do you mean available within your setup. Btw, when I used eclipse to generate webservice client classes, and used them afterwards, it works.

Comment: and through SOAP UI it works

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution for this, i'm having the same issue.